# Improper use of a variable? Codecademy - Ruby - A Night at the Movies - 1.What You'll Be Building

Tags: ruby

Here is the code that Codecademy provides:

```
movies = {
  Memento: 3,
  Primer: 4,
  Ishtar: 1
}

puts "What would you like to do?"
puts "-- Type 'add' to add a movie." 
puts "-- Type 'update' to update a movie."
puts "-- Type 'display' to display all movies."
puts "-- Type 'delete' to delete a movie."

choice = gets.chomp.downcase
case choice
when 'add'
  puts "What movie do you want to add?"
  title = gets.chomp
  if movies[title.to_sym].nil?
    puts "What's the rating? (Type a number 0 to 4.)"
    rating = gets.chomp
    movies[title.to_sym] = rating.to_i
    puts "#{title} has been added with a rating of #{rating}."
  else
    puts "That movie already exists! Its rating is #{movies[title.to_sym]}."
  end

when 'update'
  puts "What movie do you want to update?"
  title = gets.chomp
  if movies[title.to_sym].nil?
    puts "Movie not found!"
  else
    puts "What's the new rating? (Type a number 0 to 4.)"
    rating = gets.chomp
    movies[title.to_sym] = rating.to_i
    puts "#{title} has been updated with new rating of #{rating}."
  end

when 'display'
  movies.each do |movie, rating|
    puts "#{movie}: #{rating}"
   end

when 'delete'
  puts "What movie do you want to delete?"
  title = gets.chomp
  if movies[title.to_sym].nil?
    puts "Movie not found!"
  else
    movies.delete(title.to_sym)
    puts "#{title} has been removed."
  end
else
  puts "Sorry, I didn't understand you."
end
```

In the display branch of code, why is codecademy using `|movie, rating| and "#{movie}: #{rating}"`?  There is no variable defined for movie.

Since there isn't a movie variable should it not be `|title, rating| and "#{title}: #{rating}"`?

Comment: thanks, looks better!

Answer (score 1):

```
movies = {
  Memento: 3,
  Primer: 4,
  Ishtar: 1
}

movies.each do |movie, rating|
  puts "#{movie}: #{rating}"
end
```

You can look at `|movie, rating|` as brand new variables they created to use the `each` loop.

Basically, the `each` loop is iterating through the `movies` hash. Within the `movies` hash, we have movie titles and their relative ratings. So when they iterate over that hash, they are basically picking up each of the details in there and using the variables `movie, rating`, i.e.:

```
# 1st iteration
movie = Memento
rating = 3

# 2nd iteration
movie = Primer
rating = 4

# 3rd iteration
movie = Ishtar
rating = 1
```

You can name those variables anything you want, but its a good idea to make your code easily readable, so therefore they used `movie` for each of the movie titles, and `rating` for each of their relative ratings

Comment: I always remember how _why explained the block arguments in his Poignant Guide (which I think all beginning rubyists should read), quote: "{ |x,y| x + y } I like to think of the pipe characters as representing a tunnel. They give the appearance of a chute that the variables are sliding down. (An x goes down spread eagle, while the y neatly crosses her legs.) This chute acts as a passageway between blocks and the world around them." The book is available for free at http://poignant.guide/

Comment: Interesting.  I wouldn't have thought once a hash and it's variables were defined that we would redefine them later.

Comment: The `each` loop is taking a block of code (in this case the `do` and the `end`). Sometimes, blocks are defined as `movies.each { |movie, rating| puts "#{movie}: #{rating}" }`. An interesting thing about blocks are that they "create" their own scopes. So variables you define in those pipes are temporary variables you create inside the block of code to use. Once the block ends, those temporary variables "disappear".

Comment: that makes sense now! THANKS